# debug/AndroidManifest.xml elements not recognized during build in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am working on porting an existing app to a new setup and I got almost everything working, but when I tried to build the project, I got the error that some of the elements in the debug/AndroidManifest.xml are not recognized. Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Any idea why that might be happening and how to fix that?

This is my styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="home_page_buttons">  
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>    
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>   
    <item name="android:color">@color/white</item>  
    <item name="android:layout_height">45dip</item>

    <!-- <item name="android:background">@drawable/white_button</item>  -->
</style>

<style name="home_page_two_buttons">    
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>   
    <item name="android:color">@color/white</item>  
    <item name="android:layout_height">45dip</item>

    <!-- <item name="android:background">@drawable/white_button</item>  -->
</style>

<!-- Information Pages -->
<style name="instruction_text">  
    <item name="android:padding">10px</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>    
</style>

<style name="instruction_quote">  
    <item name="android:padding">10px</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>    
</style>

<style name="instruction_heading">  
    <item name="android:padding">10px</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>   
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/light_best_blue</item>      
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: what is that error showing when you keep your mouse in that errors ?

Comment: Show your style.xml file

Comment: I think may be some thing bad happen on building, please try invalidate cache  and restart your studio.

Comment: @Sree it says "attribute xyz not allowed there"

Comment: @ChiragSavsani I just added it to my original question. Thank you :)

Comment: @Sree How do I "invalidate cache?" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: I had same exception when I add some png image to drawable folder. If Image is not valid png then android studio give me that exception.

Comment: Clear the cache. File -> Invalidate Cache, then restart your IDE

Comment: @Sree I just did that and that didn't fix the problem :(

Comment: @ChiragSavsani how did you fix this issue when you had it?

Comment: Problem was in my Image. I checked my image with Hex Editor, If png file is valid then in first line in hex editor will be %png at last column. So I open that image in paint and save that file as a png.

Comment: i think you changed Theme, can you able to change to the original one ?

Comment: I think there are attributes like these names, set in Manifest.xml file. Try to add theme (style) with the name 'AppBaseTheme' & also Strings in strings.xml. May be it will solve your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned the android:theme as "AppBaseTheme" but i do not see that style in your style.xml file.